# QGIS instantly crashes on opening Data Source Manager

Tags: qgis, error, data-source

Whenever I click on the icon or the context menu for managing data sources QGIS crashes instantaneously without any error message. The problem occurs in all the latest versions of QGIS, both LTR and non-LTR.

I have tried reinstalling the software, deactivating all plugins, and installing different versions of QGIS.

The only thing that worked, but only for a short time, was to format the computer and install the latest LTR (3.28.13), but now the problem has occurred again, even on other computers in the office (both Windows 10 and 11).

On Linux computers, the problem does not occur, but changing OS is not a feasible solution for all PCs.

[image: Every method that allows to add data sources make it crash]

Comment: Have you tried creating a new clean user profile? Otherwise, It is pretty much impossible to guess what the problem might be considering the information provided.

Comment: Sysinternal's process monitor (Procmon) can be quiet useful in such cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Ivan answered to his own question:

> There was a GeoPackage added as a connection from the Data Browser,
> but then I changed its position. This was causing the crash. I removed
> the connection and the issue is gone.

Comment: Thank you, I had the same issue and could not understand the reason. An error message would be required in such situation. Now solved removing all gpkg connexions.